# In Xubuntu 16.04 how do I use the GUI to view a device name?

Tags: mount, xubuntu, sd-card, chromebook, crouton

I am on Xubuntu 16.04 running on my Chromebook through Crouton.  My end goal here is to mount my SD Card so that I may use that as the install location on Steam games as the Hard Drive on my Chromebook is very small.  The issue here is that Chromebooks by automatically add a noexec flag on to things such as SD Cards when you insert them as a security measure.  I need to add an exec flag to my SD Card from the terminal.  Before I can do that though I need to figure out the device name of my SD Card.  My old SD Card wore out, on the old one I would mount it with:

```
sudo mount -t vfat -o defaults,nosuid,nodev /dev/mmcblk1p1 /home/undyinglight/SDcard
```

The name of the old device was mmcblk1p1, however I believe the name of my new SD Card is different than the old one.  Using the GUI in Xubuntu 16.04 how do I look at the name of my new SD Card?  I knew how to do this in Ubuntu 14.04 in Unity to find the name of my old SD Card but XFCE is very different and I am struggling to find my way around this GUI.  Thank you so much.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no GUI way to display device names in Xubuntu. Use the command `lsblk -f` in a terminal to find the correct device name.

Comment: It's probably easiest to use `lsblk` in a terminal. I'm not sure if there is a partition manager installed in Xubuntu by default, but you can use e.g. `gparted` (default in Ubuntu) or `partitionmanager` (default in Kubuntu). Or you can use `gnome-disk-utility`.

Comment: Alright I did the lsblk -f and I got the following https://pastebin.com/4sDwQZMT  Which one of those is the SD Card?  I am seeing many similar names to what my old SD Card was named.  Thank you.

Comment: Either the one with 12 partitions (mmcblk0) or the one with one partition (mmcblk1). mmcblk0 is probably the internal flash memory of your Chromebook. If you want to be sure, run the command again without the SD card. The device that is missing then is the SD card.